# "The specified module could not be found." happened when call WinRT from C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, c++-cx

message

> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

StackTrace:

```
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
at winrt.Wraper.get_Instance()
at XXX.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) in c:\XXX\App.xaml.cs:line 48
```

Why this case happened?Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to use a component that is not in your appx manifest.

Comment: When I remove some code from WinRT, The Calling goes well.

Comment: I am getting the same error, did you ever fix it?